# How to disable button of one row based on input in td-element in same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm quite new to JQuery/Javascript and am trying to disable a button with `class="settle-button"` in certain rows that are placed in a dynamically generated table based on the value of a td-element with `class="total"` it.

I came up with the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $('table tr').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.total').val() == 0.00) {
            $(this).find('.settle-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.settle-button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, this code disables ALL buttons if only one happens to be 0.00. How can this code be made to change only the button in the current row? And are there other ways it can be improved?

(PS I am unable to reproduce the issue in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfEk9/3/) )

Comment: Use `.prop` instead of `.attr` : `$(this).find('.settle-button').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Thanks that's a good tip! Other tips are very welcome since I want to learn good practices.

Comment: I've got one for myself: the else part is unnecessary. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `if` statement reads wrong. `.val()` is used to get the value of a form element, input, select etc. use `.html()` to check to text in the TD.

Try this -

```
$(function () {
    $('table tr').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.total').html() == 0.00) {
            $(this).find('.settle-button').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.settle-button').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfEk9/5/)

Good point made by Karl-Andre - use `.prop`.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: At first it worked in the Fiddle but it did not work in my real web application. I found out that this was because I put the value in a '<span>'-element. While giving the span-elements a class of total the issue was solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: More than likely, are they generated on page load or at a given time (event)?

Comment: They are generated on page load.

Comment: You could try and wrap your code in `$(window).load(function(){ //Function stuff here });` which should ensure the functionality runs after the page and all content has loaded?

Comment: The other thing you may need to try is to see what value is contained within the TD itself after the content has loaded. write some code to alert() each '.total' fields html to see whats in there

Comment: Well `$(function () {` is short for `$( document ).ready(function() {`so it is ensured that it is loaded after the page is finished. I'm quite sure it works as it is supposed to, next week I will (learn how to) write unit tests to be more sure.

Comment: Your code can be shortened like that : `$(this).find('.settle-button').prop('disabled', $(this).find('.total').html() == 0.00);`. But it is maybe too "advanced" for the OP.

Comment: I Agree @Karl-AndréGagnon, I think it would be an improvement too many :)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Very nice. Can you explain how it works? What I do not get is that you give two arguments to the `.prop` operator where one is the 'disabled' property and the other is a boolean that refers to the total element. Why is this allowed and what does it do?

Comment: @user2609980 doing `$(this).find('.total').html() == 0.00` return true or false. in example, if you do `var test = $(this).find('.total').html() == 0.00; console.log(test) //==>true or false`. Since `.prop` use a boolean as parameter, you can test you condition directly into the parameters.